# create Security Group for EC2 instance on terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

i've created  security group and Instance modules after that i will pass it into main.tf file but the problem here how i could attached the value of security group into the instance  module to attached it to specfic security group

## main.tf

```
module "ec2_private" {
  source = "./module/EC2"

}

module "security_group_PS" {
  source = "./module/SG"
  name = "WebSG"
  
}
```

## ec2.tf module

```
resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  ami               = var.ami
  instance_type     = var.instance_type
  key_name          = var.key_name
  count             = length(var.availability_zones_private_ec2)
  availability_zone = var.availability_zones_private_ec2[count.index]
  subnet_id         = var.subnet_cidrs_private_ec2[count.index]
  user_data  = var.user_data_ec2_private[count.index]
 }
```

## SG.tf module

```
resource "aws_security_group" "WebSG" {
   name   = "${var.name}"

   dynamic "ingress" {
       for_each = var.ingress_rules

       content {
           description = ingress.value.description
           from_port   = ingress.value.from_port   
           to_port     = ingress.value.to_port     
           protocol    = "tcp"
           cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
       }
   }
}
```

how can i solve this problems

Comment: You need to create outputs in the SG module. You also need an argument for the security group in the `aws_instance` resource, where that argument will get a value from the variable. The variable will get the value from the SG output when calling the EC2 module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

update your sg.tf module:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "WebSG" {
  name = var.name

  dynamic "ingress" {
    for_each = var.ingress_rules

    content {
      description = ingress.value.description
      from_port   = ingress.value.from_port
      to_port     = ingress.value.to_port
      protocol    = "tcp"
      cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    }
  }
}

output "security_group_ids" {
  value = aws_security_group.WebSG[*].id
}
```

Then reference the outputs in your ec2.tf module

```
resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  ami               = var.ami
  instance_type     = var.instance_type
  key_name          = var.key_name
  count             = length(var.availability_zones_private_ec2)
  availability_zone = var.availability_zones_private_ec2[count.index]
  subnet_id         = var.subnet_cidrs_private_ec2[count.index]
  user_data         = var.user_data_ec2_private[count.index]

  // Reference the security group IDs from the output
  vpc_security_group_ids = module.security_group.security_group_ids
}
```

If you are looking for a specific security group you will need to create a local value that will help you filter the value.

Hopefully this helps.